# How mature is the Spring websocket and messaging support?

Tags: java, spring, websocket, messaging

Is the [Spring Websocket/Messaging support](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html) mature or are things still evolving awaiting some definite real cases?

I've looked at the documentation and [the sample application on github](https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-websocket-portfolio) and I see good and rapid feedback on posted issues there, with user suggestions and requests being incorporated back in the framework. For me this is an indication that things are stil evolving and taking shape.

Anyone using these capabilities in a production application?

**EDIT:** My question is related to the maturity of the new Spring modules. I'm not asking about maturity and support in browsers for web sockets. Assume I can control the browsers and they all supports websockets.

Comment: This question is *primarily opinion based*.

Answer (score 2):

One more thing to consider is where your application will run. For example Heroku "supports" websockets, but it is an experimental feature and might change at any time. So while Spring and your users' browsers might support it, you also have to make sure that your infrastructure will as well.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the opportunity to use websockets with the Spring framework, and the best answer to your question is: it really depends what's you're trying to build.

GoPivotal's done a solid job of implementing the [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) with Spring framework's Websocket API. With minimal effort you can take advantage of the  STOMP and MQTT (via Eclipse Paho) messaging protocols, making tasks such as updating a browser, mobile app, or machine in real-time relatively straight forward. Standard functionality (Suspend, Resume, Broadcast, Long Polling, Http Streaming, Native Asynchronous API) was well documented on their [WebsocketAPI support page](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html) and straight forward to execute.

Libraries such as [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere) and [JWebsocket](https://jwebsocket.org/documentation/Plug-Ins/Events-Plug-In/Developer-Guide) are available to plug-into Spring's framework which make various features easier to implement.